# Which Prestashop file do i modify to change the form method and form action of the search function?

Tags: php, prestashop, e-commerce

I have just installed the latest version of Prestashop with the default theme named classic.
I want to change the way the search function works.
Eg. change it from get to post, and change the form action to a different location, change the type of button etc.

I have attempted to modify the following files:

*public_html/modules/ps_searchbar/ps_searchbar.tpl
public_html/themes/classic/modules/ps_searchbar/ps_searchbar.tpl*

both of these files contain code that looks like it controls the search function:

```
<div id="search_widget" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 search-widget" data-search-controller-url="//www.soccersurplus.co.uk/search">
<form method="get" action="{$search_controller_url}">
<input type="hidden" name="controller" value="search">
<input type="text" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search our catalog" aria-label="Search">
<button type="submit">
<i class="material-icons search">&#xE8B6;</i>
<span class="hidden-xl-down">Search</span>
</button>
</form>
</div>
```

however, when i make changes to these files, it does not effect the search function on prestashop, and even when i delete both of the files the search still works.

Which files do i need to modify to change my search function?

my website is soccersurplus.co.uk

Thanks.

Comment: Have you clear the cache after the changes?

Comment: Clear cache and compiled files. In admin panel go to Advanced Parameters and press button Clear cache in the top right corner. Also turn off the caching on the development period, it can make you a lot of confusing